# How do I use fade-in/ease-in-out/or any animation to smooth out the revealing of my HTML, CSS and JS navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am practicing JS and CSS animations and for some reason, I am not able to enable animation when the "menu" element is using position absolute. Is there a way to use the transition to achieve the smooth sliding effect in css3 or Js?

I have tried a lot of online tutorials but none of them have worked.

Here's the codepen link: https://codepen.io/mithunbaiju/pen/XWrMqaG

```js
$("button#toggle-button").click(function(){
    $("#toggle-button").toggleClass("toggler toggler-closed-active");
    $("#main-navigation").toggleClass("site-nav site-nav-toggled");
    
});

$("button#toggle-button-closed").click(function(){
    $("#toggle-button-closed").toggleClass("toggler-closed-active toggler");
    $("#main-navigation").toggleClass("site-nav-toggled site-nav");
    
});
```

```css
html, * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.625;
}

input [type="submit"],
button{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    background-color: darkviolet;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.mast-head {
    background-color: #013243;
}

.wrap {
    padding: 2.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between
    
}

.site-branding a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: ghostwhite;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#main-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.site-nav {
    
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    transition: all .2s linear;
    
}
.site-nav-toggled {
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

.site-nav a{
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#toggle-button {
    border: 0px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.toggler-closed {
    display: none;
}

.toggler-closed-active {
    display: absolute;
    top: 2.5rem;
    right: 2.5rem;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Menu Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,400i,600,600i,700,700i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header id="site-header" class="mast-head">
        <div class="wrap">
           <div class="site-branding">
                <a href="#">Site Logo</a>
            </div>
            
            <button id="toggle-button" class="toggler">Menu +</button>
            <button id="toggle-button-closed" class="toggler-closed">Close +</button>
            
            <ul id="main-navigation" class="site-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Resourves</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your css transition on .site-nav but not on .site-nav-toggled, toggle multiple class not work, use addClass/removeClass to #main-navigation instead of toggle multiple class, you should learn chrome Devtools.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a keyframe to do the animation and apply the class on body tag.

Example of fadeIn class :-

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. @LinTao's answer did solve my problem but I understand that learning CSS animations will definitely save a lot of troubles in the long run. I have been avoiding it since it is CPU intensive and can look weird on older computers.

Answer (score 0):

I think, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) can help here a lot. Don't rush, take your time to understand the css animation property. It takes about a good hour, to get the hang of it but when you have it, it will be very fun, to use it. I just figured it out a few days ago and you can really make stuff look beautiful. I hope to have helped.

Comment: Yeah, I am actually looking into it myself. Thanks for the link. I have already started trying out a few things.

Comment: Very nice to hear that. Have fun :)